# Outer horizonal lines when inner model changes from infill to solid

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have a Creality Ender 3 Pro with only the touch sensor and filament guide as upgrades. I'm using the Creality Cura-based slicer. It prints absolutely beautifully for the price, but I'm having a small issue with the outside of the model in large prints when the inside of the model transitions from infill to a solid layer. I'm getting a protruding line around the outside for a few layers. As you can see in the photo, when the inner layer is all infill, it looks great, but when it gets to the broad flat layer, there's a little extra protrusion and the outside. It doesn't seem to happen in smaller prints. I've been searching and tried the suggestion of turning off combing and that didn't help. Has anyone else run into this issue? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a little bit of over-extrusion. When the infill is less than 100%, the walls can easily fit around it, but when the layer is all filled, the few % extra extruded material has to go somewhere and that is what pushes your outer wall outwards.
Maybe you can try to set "Outer Before Inner Walls". if that exists in the creality slicer or try cura itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll work up a test model that doesn't use as much filament and give that a try.

Comment: A solution for over extrusion is to lower the e-steps per mm for the extruder in the firmware. There are various tutorials around for dialing in the exact e-steps per mm of filament.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot. I tried the print outer layer first and it didn't help.

Comment: What's interesting, though, is that on the other side of the wall is infill, not a solid surface. It's not that the area on the other side of the outside wall is going from infill to a solid flat surface, it's that further in from the wall, the model is changing from infill to a solid surface. When I get home, I'll post a photo of the layer in the slicer that's causing the issues.

Comment: This is in the Prusa slicer I use at work, but just to give an example, this is the model I worked up to test settings. This is the layer where I get the artifact. It's still infill behind the outer wall, but inside, it transitions to a solid layer.
https://imgur.com/a/K3kSmEl

Comment: I'm wondering if it's an issue that when most of the layer is solid, it's slowing down and that's when the over-extrusion becomes more of an issue.

Comment: Yeah, Your screenshot totally disproves my point. I have no idea what causes it. I never have this issue and I use cura a lot. Try cura with the default settings maybe?

Comment: It's weird, too. I've done a ton of dialing everything in with 2 cm cubes and they are printing dimensionally accurate within 0.04 mm or so.

Comment: Just to see if it does have something to do with overextrusion still, I'm printing another test model out having backed off a touch on the steps/mm for the extrusion.

Comment: It's really weird. Backing off the steps/mm didn't change anything. I thought I'd try the Prusa slicer and that didn't make a difference, either.